Specific animated Batman movie with multiple stories
I am looking for an animated Batman movie that I've seen a long time ago but don't remember the name. It featured multiple stories about Batman in various animation styles.
I remember there were kids skateboarding at the beginning and talking about Batman saving them. Then there was a scene where Bruce Wayne travels to India, I think to learn how to become Batman. Then there is another scene where Batman gets shot in a sewer, but that's really all I can remember now.
I've been googling things like Batman movie with multiple stories, animated Batman movie where Batman trains in India, Batman movie with multiple styles of cartoon. I know its not Under the Red Hood, Dark Knight Returns or Year One. Anyone care to guess?

I'm pretty sure you're looking for Batman: Gotham Knight.
The movie is a series of smaller Batman stories, each animated by a different studio.
The segment called "Have I Got a Story for You" contains the part with the children skating and one talks about how he was saved by Batman.
The segment called "Working Through Pain" contains the part where Batman is shot in the stomach and lost wandering through the sewers of Gotham.
I don't recall a segment with him being in India, but that might just be a minor part of one of the segments.

I just Googled the movie. This is definitely it. Thank you very much.

You are looking forBatman: Gotham Knight. It is an animated film featuring 6 different more or less unconnected stories drawn in different animatin styles. It is supposed to be set in the Nolan-verse between 2005's Batman Begins and 2008's The Dark Knight, but is not actually canonical to the movies.
The 1st of the stories has a bunch of kids retell stories about them seeing the Batman in action (albeit not saving them directly). The 4th story sees him venturing into the sewers and eventually getting shot and the 5th is a flashback to his time away in India.
